# CSS Repeatable slider animation

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to create a repeatable slider using css keyframe animation only. In my project i have a div.wrapper and inside of that i have .inside-wrapper and inside ofthat i have 20 a tags with the class of box. For the css i have put for the .wrapper 1000px width and a height 200px with an overflow hidden. For my .inside-wrapper i have put the width 4000px and height 200px;. The boxes are 200px width and 200px height. Then i have create my keyframe animation using translate from 0% to be 0px and up to 100% to be -4000px;. I would like to create a repeatable animation using the forwards or an alternate animation. Can u help me create a repeatable animation using css and keyframes animation?

Thanks.

```css
* {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  background:#68a7aa;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
}

.wrapper {
  width:1000px;
  height:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:100px;
  border:3px solid #fff;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.inside-wrapper {
  width:4000px;
  height:200px;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height:200px;
}

.box {
  font-size:20px;
  color:orange;
  background:#246e93;
  display:inline-block;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  float:left;
  animation:slider-animation 10s linear 10 1s forwards;
}


@keyframes slider-animation {

  0% {
    transform:translateX(0px;)
  }

  100% {
    transform:translateX(-4000px);
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inside-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="box">1</a>
    <a href="" class="box">2</a>
    <a href="" class="box">3</a>
    <a href="" class="box">4</a>
    <a href="" class="box">5</a>
    <a href="" class="box">6</a>
    <a href="" class="box">7</a>
    <a href="" class="box">8</a>
    <a href="" class="box">9</a>
    <a href="" class="box">10</a>
    <a href="" class="box">11</a>
    <a href="" class="box">12</a>
    <a href="" class="box">13</a>
    <a href="" class="box">14</a>
    <a href="" class="box">15</a>
    <a href="" class="box">16</a>
    <a href="" class="box">17</a>
    <a href="" class="box">18</a>
    <a href="" class="box">19</a>
    <a href="" class="box">20</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the era of responsive design seeing an element hardcoded at `1000px` width is quite strange. Have you thought about using % instead? ... or have the children dictate the parent width?

Comment: Also how should exactly behave your slider? *repeatable animation*, *forwards* and *alternate* are not an enough description of what's desired.

Comment: I would like to create a slider that it goes from right to left and when its at the end of the last box, exactly next to it to be the first box and loop.

Comment: Loop what? So you mean to create an infinite slider?? Can you please explain a bit better?

Comment: yes infinite slider

Comment: **Not possible using CSS**. if your first element is at position 0, once the last element if fully visible at the right, CSS-alone cannot automagically make appear the whole set again after the last element. Use JS instead.

Comment: Well if not possible then ill use JS. Thanks Roko

Comment: Why don't you attempt some js to put it together and re-post, or use a simple framework such as flickity to get it going. Flickity is great sliders. Making sliders isn't that difficult to write on your own in js, but if you want a really pretty one you might as well just use a framework